# Windows server 2008 R2 + VMWare Workstation 7.0

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-workstation

I'm trying to install Windows 2008 R2 on VMWare, and I got this error:

> A required CD/DVD drive device driver
>   is missing. If you have a driver
>   floppy disk, CD, DVD or usb flash
>   drive, please insert it now.

I was trying to install it from ISO, daemon and from DVD drive, but always get this error.

Comment: What hardware config are you using for the Guest and do you have hardware virtualization enabled on your host?

Comment: Do you mean VMware Workstation? or ESX(i)?

Answer (score 3):

Your ISO image is corrupt.

Check with MSDN to make sure the SHA1 hash of your file is the same as what you have on your computer.  It took me 3 tries to download one with the same hash as what shows on the MSDN site.  In fact, the first one I burned to a DVD and installed on a physical machine so I thought it had to be good.

I used [fciv](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290) to verify my SHA1 in windows.

Answer (score 1):

This happens for me as well when it starts after installation (or before installation if you didn't create new VM from image): it happens to me because I have PowerISO installed which has created a virtual DVD and the machine is configured in "Settings..." to "Use physical device...: Auto Detect" and it selects the virtual DVD. Selecting an ISO, removing the DVD or manually selecting the correct device name (E: in my case) fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When installing a new machine, VMware asks you to install from:
1: Installer Disk (here you select the CD-ROM witch contains the OS, physical drive or virtual drive)
2: Installer Disk Image (and this is what you should do, select your image containing the OS you want to install)

You can set this option later in your new machine window, in the Devices tab double click on the CD/DVD (IDE) and choose Use ISO image file (browse for iso file)

hope it works
:)

Answer (score 0):

Check your VM hardware: using the "typical" installation with EasyInstall works fine on VMware workstation 7.0. If that fails, check your installation media: you might be using a corrupted ISO image.

Answer (score 0):

I second that this is most likely a corrupt .iso. I'm actually currently fighting through what appears to be an Akamai (content delivery network) node with a bad copy stored, so until I can get it to expire or assign a new node for download I'm stuck. Note that even if you're a volume licensing customer and not MSDN, the SHA1 hashes are still available to view on the MSDN site even if the downloads are not accessible (for some unknown reason they're missing from the licensing download site).

For the ...x15-59754.iso, the SHA1 is `AD855EA913AAEC3F1D0E1833C1AEF7A0DE326B0A`
For the ...x15-50365.iso, the SHA1 is `A548D6743129F2A02C907D2758773A1F6BB1BCD7`